# How to Pass the Current Object as Parameter in Access/VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to put in practice the Observer Pattern, as seen in the provided code.

the **Subject**, **Observer** and **DisplayElement** are interface classes.
**CurrentConditionsDisplay** class implements **Observer** and **DisplayElement** so it can get updated from the **WeatherData** class. as VBA doesn't support constructor with parameter, I created a sub in order to save a weatherData object and use it to register the **CURRENT OBJECT**. I pass the current object using **Me**.

when I run the main code (**WeatherStation**), the runtime error 438 comes up right when I pass **Me** as parameter (*weatherData.registerObserver (Me)*).

I'm appreciate any help.

Observer interface:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub update(temperature As Double, humidity As Double, pressure As Double)
End Sub
```

Subject interface:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub registerObserver(o As Observer)
End Sub

Public Sub removeObserver(o As Observer)
End Sub

Public Sub notifyObservers()
End Sub
```

DisplayElement interface:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub display()
End Sub
```

WeatherData subclass:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Implements Subject

Private m_observers As New Scripting.Dictionary
Private m_temperature As Double
Private m_humidity As Double
Private m_pressure As Double

Public Sub Subject_registerObserver(o As Observer)
    m_observers.Add o, o
End Sub

Public Sub Subject_removeObserver(o As Observer)
    If (m_observers.Exists(o)) Then
        m_observers.Remove (o)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Subject_notifyObservers()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objeto As Observer

    For i = 0 To m_observers.Count - 1
        Set objeto = m_observers.Items(i)
        objeto.update m_temperature, m_humidity, m_pressure
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub measurementsChanged()
    Call Subject_notifyObservers
End Sub

Public Sub setMeasurements(temperature As Double, humidity As Double, pressure As Double)
    m_temperature = temperature
    m_humidity = humidity
    m_pressure = pressure
    Call measurementsChanged
End Sub
```

CurrentConditionsDisplay subclass:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Implements Observer
Implements DisplayElement

Private m_temperature As Double
Private m_humidity As Double
Private m_weatherData As Subject

Public Sub CurrentConditionsDisplay(weatherData As Subject)
    Set m_weatherData = weatherData
    weatherData.registerObserver (Me)
End Sub

Public Sub Observer_update(temperature As Double, humidity As Double, pressure As Double)
    m_temperature = temperature
    m_humidity = humidity
    Call DisplayElement_display
End Sub

Public Sub DisplayElement_display()
    Debug.Print ("Current conditions: " + m_temperature + "F degrees and " + m_humidity + "% humidity")
End Sub
```

WeatherStation main code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function WeatherStation()
    Dim wData As New weatherData
    Dim currentDisplay As New CurrentConditionsDisplay

    Call currentDisplay.CurrentConditionsDisplay(wData)
    Call wData.setMeasurements(80, 65, 30.4)
End Function
```

Comment: `weatherData.registerObserver (Me)` since you're not using `Call` you should remove the parentheses.   And `Call` in VBA is pretty much deprecated, so it wouldn't be a bad idea to avoid it altogether.

Comment: @TimWilliams you are right! I totally forgot about the use of the parentheses. and because I was trying out different ways I missed to put Call but I removed from my code anyway. thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Freeflow thanks for the tip.I will have a have a look in your article and improve my code for sure. I need to develop systems totally stable and object-oriented. I'm also studying design patterns so I can it well structured and easier to do changes.